# C# Reflection how to get local function inside a method

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello i am trying to list all local functions inside of a method, but i dont find any way to get those methods.

Example:

[image]

I want to get the MyFunction MethodInfo, using something like Assembly.EntryPoint.GetLocalMethods()

Thanks for your time and please tell me if i was not clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimenting in sharplab, I found that all local methods are compiled to internal static methods with a name of the following form:

```
<Name1>g__Name2|x_y
```

`Name1` is the name of the surrounding method. `Name2` is the name of the local method. `x` and `y` are numbers that I don't particular know what they mean yet. They also have a `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`.

Anyway, with this information, you can find all the local methods in a method!

First you can use a regex to determine whether a `MethodInfo` is a local method of a surrounding method:

```
private static bool IsLocal(MethodInfo localMethod, string surroundingMethodName)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(localMethod.Name, "^<(\\w+)>g__(\\w+)\\|\\d+_\\d+");
    return match != null && match.Groups[1].Value == surroundingMethodName && localMethod.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null;
}
```

And then you can just do a simple `Where` filter:

```
foreach (var method in typeof(SomeClass)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(x => IsLocal(x, nameof(SomeMethod))))
{
    Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
}
```

Note that this relies heavily on implementation detail. This could very well change in the future and your code will break.

Comment: `x` is the line number of local function `Name2` within the containing method `Name1`, and `y` is the column number.

Comment: @GuneyOzsan Are they? It doesn't seem like it [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGMD2A3KCCWUAdjKkvAkcgDQAmIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUCwMwACdoIDCggN69BM4UJYAWQQFkAFAEpJ02TsWCAYpkwbJAX20zzPU0A). In this case `x` and `y` are both 0, but clearly the local function `Foo` is not on line 0.

Comment: Sorry, for me it is the line where the call is made within the local method. For example I get `<Initialize>g__FinalizeInitialization|52_1` where `Initialize` is at line 47 with the first line at 49, and `FinalizeInitialization` is at 93 where line 101 is where the stack trace call was made within the `FinalizeInitialization` (i.e. a debug log call). There 101-49 gets me to 52. Still I don't know why you get 0's.

Comment: @GuneyOzsan Interesting. This could be one of those implementation-dependent things.

Comment: There are exceptions to this rule, see my answer

Comment: Are we sure this is true in all flavors of .NET (webassembly, etc.?) Is it documented anywhere? If not I would be wary of using this in production as it could change without notice.

Comment: @PeterMoore No, as I said in the last paragraph - “this relies on implementation detail”. So it may not be true in all implementations, and I’m not aware of documentations, and I *woukd* be wary of using this in production too.

Comment: Sorry I read past that last sentence. Very good/interesting answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While the [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164730/640195) is right in most cases, there are exceptions to the rule.

Basically I found that at least in the following condition:

1. There is a lambda in the method capturing/referencing any local variable or parameter, and
2. The local method is capturing capturing/referencing any local variable or parameter (not necessarily the same as the one captured in the lambda)

In this particular case the local method will no longer be a static method in the class but an instance method in a compiler generated nested class with the class name being in the format of `<>c__DisplayClassx_y` i.e. `<>c__DisplayClass10_0` and the custom attribute will be in the class while the method will NOT have any custom attributes and the local method name will be in one of the following formats:

- `<Name1>g__Name2|x` i.e. `<MyClass>g__MyMethod|1`
- `<Name1>g__Name2|x_y` i.e. `<MyClass>g__MyMethod|1_2`

**Finding all local methods**

As such I would recommend the following code to cover all cases:

```
private static bool IsLocal(MethodInfo localMethod, string surroundingMethodName)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(localMethod.Name, @"^<(\w+)>g__(\w+)\|\d+(_\d+)?");
    return match != null && match.Groups[1].Value == surroundingMethodName;
}

foreach (var method in typeof(SomeClass)
     .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
     .Where(x => IsLocal(x, nameof(SomeMethod)) && x.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null))
     .Union(typeof(SomeClass)
            .GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null)
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic| BindingFlags.Instance)
                             .Where(x => IsLocal(x, nameof(SomeMethod))))
{
      Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
}
```

**Finding an individual method**

While to just get an individual method the following code might be more clear and have better performance:

```
public static bool IsMatchLocal(this MethodInfo localMethod, 
                     string surroundingMethodName, string localMethodName)
   => Regex.IsMatch(localMethod.Name, 
                $@"^<{surroundingMethodName}>g__{localMethodName}\|\d+(_\d+)?");

public static MethodInfo? GetLocalMethod(this Type type, 
                  string surroundingMethodName, string localMethodName)
{
     var method = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
             .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null 
                  && m.IsMatchLocal(surroundingMethodName, localMethodName));

     if(method is not null) return method;

     var nestedTypes = type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null);
     foreach(var nested in nestedTypes)
     {
           method = nested.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
              .FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsMatchLocal(surroundingMethodName, localMethodName));

           if(method is not null) return method;
     }

     return null;
}
```

**Invoking**

When it comes to invoking the method, you should note that while in the general non captured case which ends up with a static version you just pass `null` as the first argument to `.Invoke()` since it is `static`, for the exceptional case with captured variables you need to pass an actual object (which is an instance of the nested class).

The structure of the nested class appears to be one public field (not property) per each captured variable, with the same name as the captured variable, unless it is a restricted name such as `this` in which case it uses a name in the the format of `<>x__this`, for example `<>4__this`.

So to invoke the method you just need to instantiate an instance of the class, most probably by using `Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType)` and then set all fields needed, most probably by doing `nestedType.GetField(nameof(myCapturedVariable), BindingFlags.Instance)`.